# question regarding equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given a set S and a partition P of S, show that the notions of equivalence relation and partition are essentially equivalent via the following two steps.

(a) Given an equivalence relation R on S, show that the collection of the equivalence classes of R forms a partition of S.

(b) Given a partition P of S, deﬁne an equivalence relation R such that its equivalence classes form a partition of S.

Is it okay to skip (b)? They all look the same to me...

Comment: "Is it okay to skip (b)?"  No.

Comment: You are asked to show that a specific partition $P$ can be associated with a *unique* equivalence relation $\sim_P$ and furthermore that each specific equivalence relation $\sim$ can be associated with a unique partition $P_\sim$.  This implies that there is a bijection between the set of partitions of a set and the set of equivalence relations on a set.  If you were to skip part (b), we wouldn't yet have proven that multiple "different" equivalence relations don't correspond to the same partition, nor have you proven that there aren't any partitions who don't have a corresponding relation.